# How to save slivers in constants?

Tags: flutter

I'm a newbie in Flutter, and after 2 tutorials I'm trying to make my own app. As all good programmers, I don't want to repeat code. So I have a part that I'm repeating in 5 screens, and I want to save in a constant somewhere. Usually, it works with many kinds of widgets, but I'm not achieving the same result with slivers inside CustomScrollView. I replaced the actual content with this test example of sliver (a sliver list of texts), which causes the same error, so it keeps the focus in the error and not in the content.

This is the file I saved in order to bring this sliver constant.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const testSliverList = SliverList(
  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test3"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test4"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test4"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test4"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test4"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test4"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test4"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test4"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test4"),
    ),
  ]),
);
```

Here is the error:

```
Compiler message:
lib/shared/app_bar.dart:4:13: Error: Cannot invoke a non-'const' constructor where a const expression is expected.
Try using a constructor or factory that is 'const'.
  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

ps: It just raises that error when it is in a separate file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SliverChildListDelegate.fixed` instead of just `SliverChildListDelegate`. `SliverChildListDelegate` isn't a `const` constructor and therefore can't be put in a `const`.

See [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverChildListDelegate-class.html) for more reference.

Example in your code:

```
const testSliverList = SliverList(
  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate.fixed([
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test3"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test4"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test4"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test4"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test4"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test4"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test4"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test4"),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("test4"),
    ),
  ]),
);
```